# Error - Installing JDK 1.8 in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

I'v tried to install jdk 8, but it still works with jdk 7. Following are the outputs,

sudo update-alternatives --config javac

```
There is 1 choice for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac   1         auto mode
* 1            /opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac   1         manual mode
```

sudo update-alternatives --config java

```
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/java   1         auto mode
* 1            /opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/java   1         manual mode
```

javac -version

```
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

java -version

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

If you can please give me a help.
Thanks :)

Comment: This questions is a better fit for superuser.com imho, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the bellow link ,mine is working fine & I installed JDK 8 referring the link .

I think you missed update-alternatives for javac

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8*/bin/javac 1065
```

[JDK 8 Installation](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/03/15/how-to-install-oracle-jdk-8-on-linux-mint-16-petra-32-64bit-easy-guide/)